# Magento 2.3 - How to Attach file to welcome email

Tags: magento2.3, email, magento2.3.2, attachment

How do we send the welcome email with a file attached to it in magento 2.3.

I've found "Fooman Email Attachments", but it doesn't let me attach file to welcome email

Comment: can you please check https://extait.com/blog/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3/

Comment: I've tried to implement these one, but i don't know how to use it.